# Clarification on id_token vs access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, openid-connect

I'm building a system with OIDC and OAuth 2.0 (using Auth0), and I'm unsure how to properly use the `id_token` and `access_token`. Or rather, I'm confused about which roles to assign to the various services in my setup.

I have a fully static frontend-application (single-page app, HTML + JS, no backend) that ensures that the user is authenticated using the implicit flow against Auth0. The frontend-application then fetches data from an API that I am also building.

Now, which is right?

- The frontend SPA is the OAuth **client application**
- My API service is an OAuth **resource server**

...or:

- The frontend and my API service are both the **client application**

If both my frontend and backend API can be considered to be the client, I see no real harm in using the `id_token` as the bearer token on requests from my frontend to my backend - this is appealing because then I can simply verify the signed token on the backend, and I have all the information about the user that I need. However, if my API is considered a **resource server**, I should probably use the `access_token`, but then I have to connect to Auth0's servers on every API request to both verify the token, and get basic user info, won't I?

I've read [this](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis) which seems to suggest that the `access_token` is the only valid token for use with my API. But like I said, I'm not sure about the roles of the individual services. And using the `id_token` is tempting, because it requires no network connections on the backend, and contains information I need to extract the right data.

What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: I got really solid input on this over at the Auth0 forums: https://community.auth0.com/questions/10010/clarification-on-token-usage

Comment: Consider converting that forum response to an answer here, and it would help others of us in the same boat :-)

Comment: The alternative view is also valid, IMO.  Imagine you log into your application using your Google account.  You get an id_token and an access_token.  It's obvious you use the id_token for authentication to your app and the access_token to call Google APIs.  The ID token only proves you're logged in; it does not allow your app to call Google APIs on your behalf.    On the other hand, API services within "your app" have not been explicitly authorized separately as a resource server - they are equally part of "your app" whether they are accessed over HTTP or local method calls

Comment: But the spec explicitly states that the id_token must be verified:
(http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html#ImplicitFlow) 2.1.  Implicit Flow

`** 6 Client validates the tokens and retrieves the End-User's Subject Identifier.**`

Comment: So in short: how can this validation of a signed token occur in the frontend?

Comment: @ChristianJohansen, your `I've read this` link in your OP is 404'ed.  Is there an updated page you know about?

Answer (score 16):

I like this Medium post about the difference, all cred to this author.

https://medium.com/@nilasini/id-token-vs-access-token-17e7dd622084

If you are using Azure AD B2C like I am you can read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect

> **ID Token**
>
> You will get id token if you are using scope as openid. Id token is
> specific to openid scope. With openid scope you can get both id token
> and access token.
>
> The primary extension that OpenID Connect makes to OAuth 2.0 to enable
> End-Users to be Authenticated is the ID Token data structure. The ID
> Token is a security token that contains Claims(claims are name/value
> pairs that contain information about a user) about the Authentication
> of an End-User by an Authorization Server when using a Client, and
> potentially other requested Claims. The ID Token is represented as a
> [JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#JWT)
>
> ```
> {
>    "iss": "https://server.example.com",
>    "sub": "24400320",
>    "aud": "s6BhdRkqt3",
>    "nonce": "n-0S6_WzA2Mj",
>    "exp": 1311281970,
>    "iat": 1311280970,
>    "auth_time": 1311280969,
>    "acr": "urn:mace:incommon:iap:silver"
> }
> ```
>
> The above is default JWT claims, in addition to that, if you requested
> claims from service provider then you will get those as well.
>
> An `id_token` is a JWT, per the OIDC Specification. This means that:
>
> - identity information about the user is encoded right into the token    and
> - the token can be definitively verified to prove that it hasn't been    tampered with.
>
> There's a set of [rules](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation) in the specification for validating an
> `id_token`. Among the claims encoded in the `id_token` is an
> expiration (`exp`), which must be honored as part of the validation
> process. Additionally, the signature section of JWT is used in concert
> with a key to validate that the entire JWT has not been tampered with
> in any way.
>
> **Access Tokens**
>
> Access tokens are used as bearer tokens. A bearer token means that the
> bearer (who hold the access token) can access authorized resources
> without further identification. Because of this, it's important that
> bearer tokens are protected. If I can somehow get ahold of and "bear"
> your access token, I can pretend as you.
>
> These tokens usually have a short lifespan (dictated by its
> expiration) for improved security. That is, when the access token
> expires, the user must authenticate again to get a new access token
> limiting the exposure of the fact that it's a bearer token.
>
> Although not mandated by the OIDC spec, Okta uses JWTs for access
> tokens as (among other things) the expiration is built right into the
> token.
>
> OIDC specifies a /userinfo endpoint that returns identity information
> and must be protected. Presenting the access token makes the endpoint
> accessible.
>
> http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html
> https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect#cool-id-token-uses
> https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/07/25/oidc-primer-part-1

Answer (score 5):

Your frontent is your OAuth client application, once it stores the token it can take actions on the OAuth flow. And your API service is resource server, because it accepts the access_token issued by your identity server.

Also I would say that your id_token stands for the identification of the logged user and may contain sensitive data for your app. The access_token is standing as your credential to access a resource.

At the end you will use an access_token to request a resource, and then if you need specific data from the logged in user (resource owner), you may request the ID token from the token endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the first approach is correct. Your SPA is the client application and your APIs are resource servers.

I would suggest you limit the use of id_token till your SPA only. You can use the basic information present in the id token (like username and email) to display user information within your UI. If you can generate access tokens as JWTs too then your API can validate the access tokens without going to the Identity provider. You can include roles (or similar) in your access token to get authorization information in your access token.

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering if I need to talk to the IdP on every request if I'm using the tokens received from the IdP. I ended up with the following setup:

- Only the backend talks to the IdP, the frontend does not.
- Upon the IdP callback the backend issues a JWT for the frontend.
- User session and frontend-backend communication is managed entirely by my app using the JWT token.

Check this article: [OAuth2 in NestJS for Social Login (Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc)](https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/oauth2-in-nestjs-for-social-login-google-facebook-twitter-etc-8b405d570fd2)

and this repo: https://github.com/thisismydesign/nestjs-starter

and this question: [OAuth2 flow in full-stack NestJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237523/oauth2-flow-in-full-stack-nestjs-application/68036869)

Answer (score 0):

The `id_token` is an cryptographically encoded token for authentication. The OP (the auth provider) is the one that generates it and the RP (relying party or the resource) will eventually re-present the token to the OP to counter validate when handed over by the client. In short the `id_token` is tied to `authn` workflow.

The `access_token` enables resource access. It does subsume the userinfo i.e., the `id_token` or any other principal on whose behalf the access is being requested. So this token includes both user claims plus claims to groups that are authorized. In short the `access_token` is tied to your `authz` workflow.